# Is there any way to control the switches in iOS control-center

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I want to make a widget that can control the switch in iOS Settings such as ***VPN***, as circled on the photo following.

[image]

Is there any API provided by iOS which can implement the feature?

I am very very new to iOS development and I can only use Swift a little. So I wish you can give me the related API based on Swift.

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer is "No, and there never will be." Apple is very protective of the user's control of their devices. Settings like that are up to the user, and Apple wouldn't give apps the ability to change things like that due to the potential for malware to do bad things.

Comment: @DuncanC It seems that I have to accept the reality, I have done many searching but found nothing. Actually what I want to do is control switches in a more shortcut way, because I find that I can't add the control like that on Control-Center, I have to 1.open Settings -> 2. turn on/off the switch. It would be better if I could pull out Control-Center then turn on/off the switch or in a way by widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple does not provide public APIs for third-party apps to directly control system settings such as VPN or other switches. Apple typically restricts access to system settings for security and privacy reasons.

However, if your app is related to VPN functionality or you have an app extension that works with the VPN settings, you might be able to provide a toggle within your app for users to enable or disable VPN features.

Comment: Also if you try to pass those API restrictions App Store will probably reject app publication. So be careful)